# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an issue while scraping data from web

Below Mentioned I was tried

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Collect and parse first page
page = requests.get('https://www.jiosaavn.com/album/vijayashanti-birthday-telugu-hits/A05RmafpUiI_')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# Pull all text from the BodyText div
artist_name_list = soup.find(class_='song-wrap')

# Pull text from all instances of <a> tag within BodyText div
artist_name_list_items = artist_name_list.find_all('a')

for artist_name in artist_name_list_items:
    print(artist_name.prettify())
```

I except the proper output

Answer (score 0):

`find` returns `None` if it doesn't find an appropriate element. You'll need to check its return value before trying to call `find_all` on it:

```
# Pull all text from the BodyText div
artist_name_list = soup.find(class_='song-wrap')

# Check that a song-wrap item was found
if artist_name_list:

    # Pull text from all instances of <a> tag within BodyText div
    artist_name_list_items = artist_name_list.find_all('a')

    for artist_name in artist_name_list_items:
        print(artist_name.prettify())
```